# With momentjs, how do I tell if 2 moments represent the same day (not, necessarily, the same time)?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have 2 momentjs objects, `moment1` and `moment2`:

[image]

Why is `moment1.isSame(moment2, 'date')` returning false??

My understanding is that checking `moment1.isSame(moment2, 'day')` returns whether they are the same day *of the week* (at least, that's what it looks like from the docs).  So if both 'day' and 'date' don't work, what is the correct way to determine if the 2 dates represent the same day?

I could have sworn I've used `moment1.isSame(moment2, 'date')` in the past, but I must be remembering incorrectly...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use both `'day'` and `'date'` to [`isSame`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/).

As the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) says:

> Check if a moment is the same as another moment.
>
> When including a second parameter, it will match all units equal or larger. Passing in `month` will check `month` and `year`. Passing in `day` will check `day`, `month`, and `year`.
>
> Like `moment#isAfter` and `moment#isBefore`, any of the units of time that are supported for `moment#startOf` are supported for `moment#isSame`.

In the docs of [`startOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/):

> **Note:** `moment#startOf('date')` was added as an alias for day in **2.13.0**

Here a working example with the lastest version (**2.17.1**):

```js
var moment1 = moment('01/23/17', 'MM/D/YYYY');
var moment2 = moment('01/23/17', 'MM/D/YYYY');
console.log( moment1.isSame(moment2, 'day') ); // true
console.log( moment1.isSame(moment2, 'date') ); // true
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So, it's just an inconsistency in momentjs?  Elsewhere, 'day' means 'day of week' (ex: `moment1.get('day')` returns 1)?  And is this a recent change in momentjs (that `moment1.isSame(moment2, 'date')` no longer works)?  I've used the 'date' thing in the past, but someone else on my team was updating libs the other day, so maybe momentjs was one of them...

Comment: @Troy updated my answer, you can use both `date` and `day`, it works fine in the snippet. In my first answer, I didn't check that `date` works.

Comment: Apparently 'date' doesn't _always_ work.  See my original screenshot.  If 'day' is more consistent, I guess I'll just use that.

Comment: @Troy I've updated again my answer adding the version in which `date` was added. Which version of moment are you using? Can you provide a fiddle or a snippet showing your issue instead of screenshot?

Comment: I've got 2.10.3.  So if the 'date' alias was added in 2.13.0, I guess that's the problem.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11):

Let's keep it simple.

```
moment(date1).format('L') === moment(date2).format('L')
```

Comment: It's nice if you explain how you came up with this answer.

Comment: @GabrielLupu according to docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/
format('L') will convert momentDate into string, example: `09/04/1986`.
so in the end we will compare 2 strings. 2 date strings. without time.

Answer (score 5):

More simple, use the function [isSame](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/02-is-same/)

```
moment('2010-01-01').isSame('2010-02-01', 'day');
```